# Flow Variable collection to Flow variable

Tags: visual-workflow, collection-variable

I'm trying to iterate over customobject records where there is Master-Detail lookup to Account Object on this customobject. I'm storing accountId for each customobject record into Collection Variable. But that collection have duplicate values, and I need to get value of those AccountId(No Duplicate) stored in single variable as text.

Here is AccountIds collection variable that stored AccountIDs.

[image]

But as you see they have duplicate values in them. and I need to pass this Id's in single variable Text type without duplicate values.

Comment: you want to convert the collection variable into a scalar variable with duplicates removed - by concatenating the unique values into a single delimited string? I guess I would ask "why"

Comment: @cropredy I'm using this Ids in other component "LookupFSC" in which i'm doing lookup on Account and for filter I can use variable or formula but it will not accept collection variable. However one small clarification that if Ids are duplicate it won't matter, It just needed to be in ('0011U00000oyv8UQAQ','0011U00000oyv8YQAQ','0011U00000oyv8UQAQ') format.
[Here is question that will make more sense I guess](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301400/flow-formula-help-to-format-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this dedup extension: https://unofficialsf.com/de-dupe-an-sobject-collection-and-schedule-an-email-in-flow/

Once you have your collection of accounts deduped, you can use the [Extract Fields from Collection](https://unofficialsf.com/new-collection-processor-actions-1-count-fields-and-records-and-2-extract-fields-from-records/) extension to get your list of ID's