# Flow formula help to format string

Tags: formula, visual-workflow

I have Flow with collection variable {!AccountIds} and it's value is following

{!AccountIds} = "[0011U00000oyv8UQAQ,0011U00000oyv8YQAQ,0011U00000oyv8YQAQ,0011U00000oyv8UQAQ]"

I'm using Formula in flow to fetch all value and get it as string.

[image]

so Now when I use this formula in Text component it shows

[image]

However I need this Values to be formated in this format

('0011U00000oyv8UQAQ','0011U00000oyv8YQAQ','0011U00000oyv8YQAQ','0011U00000oyv8UQAQ')

Is there any way this possible?

Comment: why are the accountIds all in a single string - what is the source of this string?  Can that source be adapted to provide a collection rather than a delimited string? If not, you need to use invocable apex to split and return as a collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace the characters in the `AccountsIds` variable. In the formula below are three levels of `SUBSTITUTE`. First to replace `,` with `','`, second to replace `[` with `('`, and last one to replace `]` with `')`.

```
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
SUBSTITUTE(
{!AccountID},"]","')"),
"[","('"),
",","','")
```